# 招待人 for "host" of guests or visitors (e.g., our "host" was kind)?

Tags: translation, mandarin, cantonese

主持人 means the host of a show or event.

What is the right word for someone who entertains or hosts guests? 招待人？

For instance, assume this sentence:

Alice thought Bob was a kind and hospitable host.

1. How would you say this in Cantonese?
2. How would say this in Mandarin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**主人**

*Tuttle*

> N
>
> 1 
>   host (antonym 客人 kèren)
>
> 客人都来了, 主人呢? 
>   Kèren dōu lái le, zhǔrén ne?
>   The guests have all arrived, but where is the host?

As a verb you can try **做东** aswell.

*Words.HK*

> 動詞
>   作為主人家招待客人
>   to be the host
>
> 你嚟我屋企, 我做東。 
>   nei5 lai4 ngo5 uk1 kei2, ngo5 zou6 dung1.
>   Come to my house, I will be the host.

Both work in Mandarin and Cantonese.

Kind and hospitable host I would translate like:

做东做得友好又大方

Answer (score 2):

I'd just go with 人。

Alice thought Bob was a kind and hospitable host.
爱丽丝认为鲍勃是个和蔼好客的人。

Comment: Agree, but please note that this only works in this specific context. In other situations, it's better to say 主人.

Answer (score 1):

what is the right word for someone who entertains or hosts guests? 招待人？
you can call it  “主人”. but it is barely used .you sometimes can see it in paper .In oral spoken,we juet ignore it ,you can call  the name or palace name streatly 
For instance：这家主人正在招待客人=This host is  entertaining guests 
≈这家餐厅正在招待客人，Bob一家正在款待客人 这家人正在招待客人

Alice thought Bob was a kind and hospitable host.
Alice认为Bob是一个热情好客的人。

"主人" was commonly use in servent who begged the master or BDSM(some call the lord)or old ancient servent who faced with the empire

when you use it between country .you can call it  “东道主”